# How to extend multiple descendants of a common base?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I would like to write an editor plugin for Eclipse that extends all text editors. The problem is that if I subclass [AbstractTextEditor](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/texteditor/AbstractTextEditor.html) then I will lose all the inherited classes' functionality of course.
How can I do that without having to reimplement those?

Edit: Some more details. I would like to add 1) vim-like commands, 2) modal editing, 3) modeline on the bottom.

Comment: It would be better if you could be more specific?  What exactly are you trying to achieve?  There are several extension points you can use depending on your goals.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to write an editor plugin for Eclipse that extends all text editors.

You certainly can't write a plugin that contains all the functionality of multiple text editors simultaneously if the assorted text editors do different and contradictory things.

But if you're trying to make something that can modify the behavior of any other text editor, you want to look at the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Precisely how this will interact with the Eclipse plugin architecture is unclear to me, but if your know the need, it may be clearer to you.

Comment: I don't want it to contain all the functionality of other editors simultaneously. I want to add functionality to all editors that inherit AbstractTextEditor. Decorator pattern is a good idea, but I don't know how to apply it here; the Eclipse plugin architecture is a HUGE beast.

Answer (score 0):

Make a composition of classes.

```
class MyTextEditor extends AbstractTextEditor {

  AnotherEditor ed1;

  AnotherEditor ed2;

}
```